# Reusable jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

i create a script for sliding div, but i want reuse it on another block in my dom.

like

```
$("div").InfiniteRotator(init);
```

How can do it?   [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7tt0dmh/)

Comment: you need to learn [how to create a jQuery plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)